# What happens with stripe when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

If the user has the javascript disabled in her browser, Does Stripe degrades gracefully or just breaks?

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you disable JavaScript from your own browser?

Comment: I'm in a work PC where I can't disable the javascript to test it, hence the question.

Comment: I answered initially, but giving it a thought, you probably should just ask it straight from their help & support site: https://support.stripe.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is specific to online payment provider and should be instead ask from their support.

Comment: There is a tag for "stripe-payments" with 995 questions, all specific to Stripe. For example other very specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19467287 has 11 votes, 6 stars and 4k views.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to click the Stripe button that opens the pop-window on my site, with Javascript turned off, and nothing happens. There's a short delay between the clicks but other than that, nothing happens.

Might be helpful to add a `<noscript>` tag.